# Twitter Oauth Node.js Express console.log not showing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twitter, passport.js

I am using the following code to implmenet twitter Oauth in node.js.  The token and tokenSecret are not showing up in the console.

Everything else is working correctly, like the login, authentication, and callback functions.

All I see in the console are the access logs like the following:

GET / 304 197.320 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 2.092 ms - -
GET /auth/twitter 302 404.252 ms - 0

All I want to do is show the access token and access secret of the authenticated user.

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var passport = require('passport');
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var config = require('./config');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret-key',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// passport-twitter settings
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: config.consumerKey,
    consumerSecret: config.consumerSecret,
    callbackURL: config.callbackURL
  },
  // After authentication

  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    console.log("token: " + token);
    console.log("tokenSecret: " + tokenSecret);
    return done(null, profile);
  }
));
// Save to session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/success', usersRouter);
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/?auth_failed' }), 
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/success');
  });




// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the callback url in the twitter app page to "http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback" and it worked.